# If-statement not behaving as expected

Tags: python, list, if-statement, comparison

I am trying to do a comparison between two lists and I dont want a user to be printed if he exists in both source and destination database. I tried to use a if statment, but for some reason I dont understand, even though user "Will" exists in destination database, he is still being printed. would you please help me figuring this out? thank you

```
source_database = [("John","Smith","1985"),("Will","Tomson","1958")]
destination_database = [("John","Smith","1985"),("Will","Tomson","1956")]

users_to_add = [user for user in source_database if user not in destination_database]
for users in users_to_add:
    if users not in  destination_database:
        print(users)

else:
    continue
```

Output:

```
('Will', 'Tomson', '1958')
```

Comment: "even though user "Will" exists in destination database" - yes, but `("Will","Tomson","1958")` (which is `users` in your code) does not

Answer (score 1):

The `in` statement checks the contents of the tuples its comparing. So since one tuple has "1958" in it and one has "1956" the tuples do not have equivalent contents.

Edit:

One solution would be to create a list of the names from the source database and check to see if the users name is in there.

```
source_users = [x[0] for x in source_database]

users_to_add = [user for user in source_database if user not in destination_database]

for users in users_to_add:

    if users[0] not in source_users:

        print(users)
```

Comment: I understand that, so that is why I am trying to add this if statement after the comparison.
after the comparison if the user[0] exists in both lists, then it shouldnt be printed. Although I tried to add this, the result is the same:

for users in users_to_add:
    if users[0] in  destination_database[0]:
        continue
    
    else:
        print(users)

Comment: Oh ok I see. So you want it to reject the whole tuple if the first name is in both databases?